# How to pass variables to a curl command using Shelex

Tags: python, shell

I am using the below curl command in python and I am successfully able to run it. But I want to store auth id and tenant Id in a variable and then use that variable in curl command. Please let me know how can I do it. Thank you in advance.

```
import shlex
auth_id = 'test'

tenant_id = 'testt'
cmd = '''curl -X POST -i -u auth_id@tenant:password -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d '{"rotate": 23.07, "pressure": 45.85}'  
http://localhost:8080/telemetry'''
args = shlex.split(cmd)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pycurl instead:

```
import pycurl
import json

headers = ['Content-Type: application/json']
data = json.dumps({"rotate": 23.07, "pressure": 45.85})

credentials = 'username:password'

p = pycurl.Curl()
p.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
p.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
p.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
p.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
p.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, credentials)
pass_url=str("http://localhost:8080/")
p.setopt(pycurl.URL, pass_url)
p.perform()
p.close()
```